# Why does this Prolog code not run?

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have written the following code to replace all occurrences of a given element in a list, with another specified value. Here's my code:

```
substitute(X, Y, [], []).
substitute(X, Y, [X|T], [Y|R]) :- substitute(X, Y, T, R).
substitute(X, Y, [H|T], [H|R]) :- H\= X, substitute(X, Y, T, R).
```

I am trying to call it like this in GNU Prolog:

```
substitute(2, 3, [2, 2, 2], []).
```

which results in:

```
no
```

What is wrong here? I don't see anything wrong. I am comparing the head of my given list to see if it matches X. If it matches, I replace it in the output list by Y and I recurse on the tail.

In the second case, if the head doesn't match to X, then I recurse on the tail and check if an element of the tail is same as X and then the recursion replaces it as per the 2nd definition. Then at the end of the tail, when an empty list is encountered, the recursion moves to the base case and terminates. I am not sure, why I am not able to run this code. Help please.

Comment: What shoud be proper output to `substitute(2, 3, [2, 2, 2], X).`?

Comment: [3, 3, 3]. I described that above.

Comment: Then what is your problem exactly? If proper output should be`[3, 3, 3]` and not `[]` then GNU Prolog **correctly** states that answer to `substitute(2, 3, [2, 2, 2], []).` is `no`.

Comment: oooh. I thought that it was supposed to print out to me the new list.